# with/without + verbless clause

Tags: clauses

*The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language* (Page 1266-67) has this section:

> **10 Verbless clauses**
>
> We confine our attention here to verbless clauses in dependent or supplement functions comparable to those realised by non-finite clauses, as described in the main part of the chapter.
>
> **(a) Complement to *with* and *without***
>
> [1] i *They were standing against the wall* [*with **their hands above their heads***].
>
> ii *They were wandering around* [*without **any clothes on***].
>
> iii [*With **the children so sick**,*] *we weren’t able to get much work done.*
>
> iv *Who is that guy* [*with **his hands in his pockets***]*?*
>
> The [boldfaced] clauses have subject + predicate structure, but with no verb in the predicate. *With* and *without* do not license finite complements, but non-finites are found in addition to the verbless forms (see §8.3 above). The bracketed PPs function as adjunct to a clause ([i–iii]) or post-modifier in NP structure ([iv]). *With* is semantically similar to *have*, and *without* to *not have*: [i–ii], for example, entail *They had their hands above their heads*, *They didn’t have any clothes on*.

CGEL is saying the boldfaced portions are verbless clauses and "have subject + predicate structure". But is that true?

As suggested by CGEL, *with*/*without* can be replaced with *having*/*not having* in [i, ii, iv] as follows:

> (1) *They were standing against the wall* [*having **their hands above their heads***].
>
> (2) *They were wandering around* [*not having **any clothes on***].
>
> (4) *Who is that guy* [*having **his hands in his pockets***]*?*

Here, can you say that *having* take verbless clauses as complements? I don't think you can. In (1), (2), and (4), I think that *having* takes ***their hands***, ***any clothes***, and ***his hands***, respectively, as its direct objects.

Note, on the other hand, that *with* cannot be replaced with *having* in [iii]:

> (3) ??[*Having **the children so sick**,*] *we weren’t able to get much work done.*

In [iii], unlike in [i], [ii], or [iv], **the children so sick** *is* a verbless clause and does have subject + predicate structure.

But is it correct to treat the boldfaced portions in [i], [ii], and [iv] as verbless clauses as well?

Comment: Being a clause is not something that can be "true". It's a part of CGEL's analysis, so you gotta believe it if you follow them. This also affects CGEL's definition of "clause", since the system is unified.

Comment: @JohnLawler I'm asking if you can discern that the boldfaced portion in [iii] is different from those in [i], [ii] and [iv].

Comment: Not notably. ii is negative, wth an NPI, iii uses the _so_ of _so ...that_ construction, so both of those have special bonds to the other part of the sentence. But they're all the same construction. If you or CGEL want to call them "verbless sentences", you can't be stopped. Or if you don't nobody's forcing you. That's the way science goes -- no analysis is perfect, and even the best are often forced to adopt analyses they don't admire.

Comment: @JohnLawler In the last part of the quoted portion, CGEL says "_With_ is semantically similar to _have_, and _without_ to _not have_" But this doesn't seem to apply to [iii], because [iii] doesn't seem to entail _We had the children so sick_. What do you make of this?

Comment: Nothing in particular. I'm not interested in what CGEL says. The _have_ in the example is not the _have_ of possession, but occurrence or achievement, like _They have the water boiling_. That's the construction that ultimately led to the present perfect: _I have dinner cooked_ => _I have cooked dinner_. That's why _have_ is the auxiliary for the perfect.

Comment: @JohnLawler Does (3) work for you in your reading of _having_ as "occurrence or achievement"? (3) _Having the children so sick, we weren’t able to get much work done._

Comment: Occurrence, certainly. _With the weather so ....._, for instance, can be used with just about any appropriate adjective and succeeding clause. Occurrences occur continuously. ***I*** still wouldn't call it a clause, but that's just me; it's the remains of a clause.

Comment: @JohnLawler I was asking about (3) _Having..._, not [iii] _With..._.

Comment: There's no difference in structure.

Comment: @JohnLawler Do you think that (3) _Having..._ sounds as idiomatic as [iii] _With..._?

Comment: There's no difference; both are common and they mean the same. Like most such constructions in English, it's still coming together, and there's a lot of ways to do it. English only invented syntax about 600 years ago and we're not that good with it yet.

Answer (score -2):

The "verbless clause" analysis seems to be motivated by the absence of a verb in constructions like "with their hands above their heads".

"Having their hands above their heads" and "not having any clothes on" do contain a verb (*having*). So I don't see why would would analyze these constructions as containing a "verbless clause".

Comment: This is more a comment than an answer. Moreover, the 'verbless clause' CGEL is talking about is only the boldfaced portion, not the with-PP. So, I'm not asking whether "Having their hands above their heads" is a verbless clause, I'm asking whether the part "their hands above their heads" (after "Having") is.